# Fiddler consumes data even when the streaming tab is closed in the browser

Tags: streaming, fiddler

I am new to Fiddler.
But when I developing a tool I noticed a strange thing when Fiddler is running.

I go to a particular steaming link that has a .mp4 file from my web browser and just after viewing a little part of the video (still not whole video is buffered), I close the tab.
But I see that Fiddler process continues to consume some data even though I do not do any thing after that. Seems it downloads whole streaming file although I close it. Consumes more data when the link time is higher. 
I can see the bandwidth consumption and data consumption through traffic monitor that fiddler process consumes data. 
This does not happen for every streaming site it seems. And it only happens when the fiddler is open for this problematic site. 
I get this problem either the streaming button is enable or not (if that has any connection)

Do we have any option to disable this in Fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > Fiddler Options > Performance. Adjust the Streaming dropdown as desired.